# Add an additional text to product title in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Need some help here is a snippet that adds additional text to woocommerce product title.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );

function woocommerce_template_single_title_custom(){
    $additional_text = 'Additional Text';
    the_title( '<h3 class="product_title entry-title">', $additional_text.'</h3>' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title_custom', 5);
```

What i need is this code to work only for specific product id's.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `product_id` before inside the function.

```
function woocommerce_template_single_title_custom(){
    global $product;
    if($product->get_id() == 123){
        $additional_text = 'Additional Text';
        the_title( '<h3 class="product_title entry-title">', $additional_text.'</h3>' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title_custom', 5);
```